# When to use document.write()?

Tags: php, javascript

I was told not to use `document.write()` by and SO member.  That innerHTML is better, or better yet, manipulate the DOM directly.

However, If I'm loading a page for the first time and there is content that is stored on a mysql table, and hence it will be converted to HTML, how can I do this if I don't want the server doing this task?

If the server did it then I could just have PHP code generate the html and place it where needed..but b.c. I want Javasrcript(client) to render the HTML I use this code (which is generated by php, but less processing time, as it does not create the HTML)

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>document.write(Arc.ViewHBookmark('google.com|http://www.google.com|Google||ideeli.com|http://www.ideeli.com|Ideeli||kikin.com|http://www.kikin.com|Kikin||lot18.com|http://www.lot18.com|Lot18||twitter.com|http://twitter.com|Twitter'))</script>
```

This is how I have the client generate HTML on a page reload.  Embedded Javascript with a document.write().

Is there a better way to do this?  By better I mean a way that does not use document.write().

I can call a javascipt function that renders the HTML on the onload event, but how would I have access to the JSON data or similar(AML) in this case.

I could write it into the page..and then read it back in, generate the content, and write it back to the page...but this seems more inefficient than just using `document.write()`

Is it O.K to use `document.write()` in this case?

If not, is writing structured data to the page and having javascript convert it to HTML considered good practice?

Comment: I think is for this that the server exists...

Comment: I have seen far more browsers fail than servers lately. Putting more processing to javascript can really slow down your website for the user. Besides, PHP runs far more fficiently than JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, make javascript objects that hold your database data, and then render your page depending on how the javascript objects are built.

Comment: Travis,  What is better to generate the DOM elements or just create text and place it in .innerHTML?

Comment: Well, it really comes down to how much code your javascript takes up.  The nice thing about having a function that creates a DOM object and then inserts it is that you can use it for multiple tasks versus if you just blankly use .innerHTML all the time you could end up with a huge js file that is building strings and inserting them into innerHTML areas.  Best practice is to reduce redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know exactly what `Arc.ViewHBookmark` is supposed to do exactly, but it seems that it's returning HTML. So the answer is simple: make it manipulate the DOM directly (e.g. add elements dynamically) instead of having it return HTML strings. And then call it without wrapping it in `document.write`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can just use a `div` (or, depending on context, maybe `span`) element with empty content where you now have the 'script` element, e.g.

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

and then use JavaScript that puts the generated content into that element:

```
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = Arc.ViewHBookmark(...);
```

(You can put that e.g. into a `script` element that you place after the `div` element.)